# Trying to select data and then do a average on the selected data in mariadb

Tags: sql, xampp, mariadb

SELECT counts
FROM (SELECT COUNT(`ch_id`) AS counts
FROM tbl_warrants_checked
WHERE `status` = "active"
GROUP BY `dateChecked`);

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please describe what you want.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I would like to count the ID columns and group it by dateChecked witch was the day they checked the warrants, then i need the average of the amount of warrants that was checked on that day, to post to my dahsbaord as an avegrage of warrants checked per day for the last month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses MariaDB 10.5, but should work with any version since ~10.2.2.

If we assume every day has data, or we don't care about the days which have no data, the following will calculate the average checks per day since 1 month ago (the last month of data):

```
-- Average of counts per day since ~1 month ago.
-- Only for days present in the set
SELECT AVG(counts) AS average
  FROM (
          SELECT COUNT(ch_id) AS counts
            FROM tbl_warrants_checked
           WHERE status = 'active'
             AND dateChecked > (current_date - INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
           GROUP BY dateChecked
       ) AS x
;
```

Sample result:

```
+---------+
| average |
+---------+
|  3.2941 |
+---------+
```

If we wish to account for missing days and treat them as 0, the following generates the days since 1 month ago and `LEFT JOIN`s that with the found counts per day:

```
-- Average of counts per day since ~1 month ago.
-- Treat missing days as 0
WITH RECURSIVE dates (date) AS (
          SELECT current_date UNION ALL
          SELECT date - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM dates
           WHERE date > (current_date - INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
     )
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(counts, 0)) AS average
  FROM dates AS d
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT dateChecked
               , COUNT(ch_id) AS counts
            FROM tbl_warrants_checked
           WHERE status = 'active'
             AND dateChecked > (current_date - INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
           GROUP BY dateChecked
       ) AS x
    ON d.date = x.dateChecked
;
```

Sample result:

```
+---------+
| average |
+---------+
|  1.7500 |
+---------+
```

[Working test case with data which produces the above results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7314d0a5bf5853e01e17c262b288325c)

Note: We could also have calculated the missing days and used that in the final calculation without the recursion and `JOIN`.  There's another simplification available as well.